# Apache htaccess 301 redirect with special characters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Really struggling with this, all 301 redirects in htaccess (the ones without special characters) are working apart from this one. I need to redirect from

`/folder1/departmentpage.html/customerx/_438081/1/Sofabeds%2520for%2520Small%2520%252D%2520Medium%2520or%2520Large%2520Rooms`

TO

`http://www.newsite.com/sofabeds`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just that specific one please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something as simple as this.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)Sofabeds(.*)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newsite.com/Sofabeds [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. That almost worked, but as soon as you test with %2520 in the source URL, it doesn't work, and redirects to the root of the site. Any ideas on how to handle kthe %2520's please?

Comment: Scratch that, all seems to be working now...thanks for your help!